# Pod didn't trigger scale-up because "max node group size reached"

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I use GKE in Google Cloud Platform, and encountered the following error message.

> pod didn't trigger scale-up: 12 node(s) didn't match Pod's node
> affinity/selector, 3 max node group size reached.

I look for the cause of this issue, but cannot find any answer.

Does anyone know the cause of this issue? Also, I would appreciate if you tell me about the solution for this error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: i think the error itself is explanatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that Pod is waiting to get scheduled on a node, but suitable node cannot be found. Cluster Autoscaler can't do anything in any of the available node pools and their zones - it still wouldn't fit if a new node is added:

- for 12 combinations of (node pool + zone): node(s) didn't match Pod's node affinity/selector
- for 3 combinations of (node pool + zone): max node group size reached - provisioned node count >= autoscaling.maxNodeCount

Also GKE has an option to enable [node auto-provisioning](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-auto-provisioning)